# Sharepoint/OneDrive - how to exclude a folder from search?

Tags: office365, onedrive, microsoft-onedrive, sharepoint-online

I want to search in OneDrive (online, using Browser). But as I know, this is in fact a Sharepoint.

How has the search string has to look like to find only those files in my documents, that are **not contained in a specific folder**?

I already spotted [the search operators (KQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dev/general-development/keyword-query-language-kql-syntax-reference) and [the possibly searchable properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/SharePoint/technical-reference/crawled-and-managed-properties-overview).
But I miss a **property** like "**folder**".

Interestingly, searching for
`folder=example` finds all files with "example" in their name or content
`folder="example"` finds nothing
`folder=Documents` finds all my documents
`folder="Documents"` finds nothing, not even the files from the root dir
`foolder=example` finds nothing, which means to me, that the property `folder` is somehow recognized
And it does not work to extend `folder=Documents` with any subfolder using `/` or `\` or `>`.